# Add folder in project setup

Tags: vb6

How to add new folder in vb6 project? I have a form and form uses some images now i want to move all the images under the folder images under the project in vb6 ? and later will reference the images from this folder.

Comment: What are you asking?  Do you mean through the GUI or in the FS (and using the vbproj files?)

Comment: through GUI. like you do in visual studio. right click--> add new folder .

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it in the VB6 GUI. It has a fixed layout - remember it is 15 years old and things (and projects in particular) were much simpler.

You can however have the files themselves in different folders. You can create subfolders on disk and move the files into there. 'Save As..' may work for the individual files. If you want to do quite a lot of files:

1. Start a new project
2. Distribute the files into the folders you require
3. Use 'Add Files' to add the files from each folder.